# Okhttp interceptor Null pointer exception issue when internet is not available

Tags: okhttp

I have okhttp interceptor in our app and it working fine when internet is available. But when internet is not available and when app comes to foreground getting null pointer exception.

```
2020-06-29 16:57:21.376 31124-31237/com.cba.tymecoach E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.cba.tymecoach, PID: 31124
    java.lang.NullPointerException: interceptor com.cba.tymecoach.CustomResponseInterceptor@fff543d returned null
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:502)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```